# GetDlgItemText can't get the data

Tags: c, text, dialog, getlasterror

```
LONG DoDlg(HWND hDlg,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDOK:
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg,IDC_EDIT2,(LPWSTR)Mask,255);
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg,IDC_EDIT3,(LPWSTR)Gateway,255);
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg,IDC_EDIT1,(LPWSTR)IPAddress,255);
            DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();//the value is 6
            char buf[100]={0};
            sprintf(buf,"%d",dwErrorCode);
            SetIPInfo(IPAddress,Mask,Gateway);//this is my function
            MessageBox(hDlg,(LPCWSTR)buf,TEXT("hehe"),MB_OKCANCEL);
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg,0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The three GetDlgItemText always has some problem.
Now the first and the second is OK,and the last IPAddress get nothing from Edit control.
If i change the order,maybe Mask or Gateway will get nothing.
the GetLastError is 6.

Comment: I am sorry,now  the Gateway is NULL,and the others is OK,I just change the order.

Comment: Is it always the last calls that return NULL?

Comment: No,the order like IPAddress,Mask,Gateway,IPAddress is NULL

Comment: If Mask,Gateway,IPAddress,Gateway is NULL.

Comment: Is it consistent? Does the same order always results in the same results?

Comment: Yeah,same order results same results.